# Magento 2 enable merging/bundling after AdvancedJS Bundling

Tags: magento2, performance, jsbundling

I have recently applied AdvancedJS Bundling on my Magento 2 store, and the performance is quite improved. But for Advanced JS Bundling, the merging, and bundling is disabled. Can I enable that also after AdvancedJS Bundling or it shouldn't be?

Answer (score 1):

As with all sites now using https so recommendation is to use http2( needs a site on https ) and not http1 as http protocol.

If you have your site running on http2 then there is no need to merge JS files, with http2 multiple files are downloaded in stream.

Comment: Can you guide on how to change http protocol to http2?